# An question about the integer set.

Tags: combinatorics

**Question** Let $A\subseteq B\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $|A|=n$ be a given positive integer.Let $\overline{A}=\{x:x=a+b,(a,b)\in A^2\}$,$\overline{B}=\{x:x=a+b,(a,b)\in B^2\}$.If $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$,find the possible maximum value of $|B|$.

**My idea** I have found a bound of $m=|B|$. On the one hand,$\overline{A} $ has at most $n(n+1)/2$ elements,and let $B=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_m\}$ where $a_1<a_2<...<a_m$. So $2a_1,a_1+a_2,2a_2,...,a_{m-1}+a_m,2a_m$ are different elements in $\overline{B}$,which implies $2m-1<n(n+1)/2$.On the other hand take $n=3k-2$,$A=\{1,2,...,k,2k,3k,...,k^2-k,k^2-k+1,...,k^2\}$,$B=\{1,2,...,k^2\}$ ,so$\overline{A}=\overline{B}$,and $m>2k^2>n^2/9$.Therefore we get $n^2/9<|B|<n^2/4$.

So  can anyone  give  the maximum value of $|B|$ or an exacter bound?